# Use of preposition after 'Follow-up'

Tags: prepositions

Could someone suggest what preposition to use after 'Follow-up'? Is it 'on' or 'of' or 'to'?

The background to the question above is an event that has happened, and (which) needs to be 'followed up': for example, consider the following sequence of events:

1. a person enters into an email conversation (series of back and forth emails getting exchanged)
2. After a while, he wants to sends a separate mail to pursue (follow-up) the earlier matter.

The question is, what should he use as the subject of this new email. Should it be:

- (a) Follow-up on the earlier matter (he means to say, I am following up on the earlier matter)
- (b) Follow-up of the earlier matter (meaning - this new email is a follow-up of the earlier matter)
- (c) Follow-up to the earlier matter (intention to state that the new email is a  follow-up to the matter that was earlier discussed)

Comment: From your options, on. I have also personally used "with". More context would help.

Comment: Yes, more context, please. Any of those could be used after "follow-up" depending on the sentence it appears in.

Comment: I needed to put up a phrase for a program which goes like: 'Follow up ..... XYZ - An Interaction Program' I need to put the preposition in the blank where XYZ is a past event. @THEAO

Comment: Again, there's still not quite enough context to tell you what you should say... If this is some kind of an alert that pops up, telling the user to "Follow up ... XYZ" I wouldn't use follow up at all. I would say something like "Program XYZ needs your attention". Or even better, figure out what's going on with the code and tell them what to do. If you're sending messages to people and asking them to follow up, for example "on" a task you asked them to complete, or "with" a specific individual, then I would use follow up. Still not enough context.

Answer (score -1):

As an idiom, we use : To follow up. In sentence, we can use as "on follow up" or "upon follow up". depends upon the sentence construction what suits better..